# Does the w:style with the w:type="table" and w:default="1" attribute automatically apply to a w:tbl without a w:tblStyle?

Tags: openxml

I found a table has a padding sytle, but its `w:tbl` does not have a `w:tblStyle`. Does the `w:style` which has the `w:type="table"` and `w:default="1"` attributes have an effect in this case?

The background is that I'm using XSLT to transform the Open XML markup.

Comment: As a green hand, please let me know the reason why givng a downvoting, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "Yes"; the default style will apply if no style is explicitly assigned.

There are four different types of styles in WordprocessingML, i.e., `paragraph`, `character`, `table`, and `numbering` styles. For each type (e.g., `table`), one style is marked as the default style for related Open XML elements (e.g., `w:tbl` elements) by having an attribute `w:default="1"`. The typical default styles are shown below:

```xml
  <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:default="1" w:styleId="Normal">
    <w:name w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:qFormat/>
  </w:style>

  <w:style w:type="character" w:default="1" w:styleId="DefaultParagraphFont">
    <w:name w:val="Default Paragraph Font"/>
    <w:uiPriority w:val="1"/>
    <w:semiHidden/>
    <w:unhideWhenUsed/>
  </w:style>

  <w:style w:type="table" w:default="1" w:styleId="TableNormal">
    <w:name w:val="Normal Table"/>
    <w:uiPriority w:val="99"/>
    <w:semiHidden/>
    <w:unhideWhenUsed/>
    <w:tblPr>
      <w:tblInd w:w="0" w:type="dxa"/>
      <w:tblCellMar>
        <w:top w:w="0" w:type="dxa"/>
        <w:left w:w="108" w:type="dxa"/>
        <w:bottom w:w="0" w:type="dxa"/>
        <w:right w:w="108" w:type="dxa"/>
      </w:tblCellMar>
    </w:tblPr>
  </w:style>

  <w:style w:type="numbering" w:default="1" w:styleId="NoList">
    <w:name w:val="No List"/>
    <w:uiPriority w:val="99"/>
    <w:semiHidden/>
    <w:unhideWhenUsed/>
  </w:style>
```

For example, if you have `w:p` (paragraph), `w:r` (run), or `w:tbl` (table) elements without an explicit style being assigned to them (e.g., using `w:pStyle`, `w:rStyle`, or `w:tblStyle`), the default styles for those types of elements will apply.